# Craft sitemap 'Internal Server Error'

Tags: plugin-sitemap

i am getting an 'Internal Server Error' when I go to my 'domain.com/sitemap.xml' page. The plugin itself loads fine in the backend and I can change all the settings etc.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Malcolm

Comment: Can you deactivate the devMode and report the error to us?

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the reply. Should I email it to you or another specific email address or through something else?